# Math.random on non whole numbers

Tags: lua, coronasdk

How can I generate numbers that are less than 1?

for example i would like to generate numbers from 0.1 to 0.9

what I've tried:

```
math.random(0.1,0.9)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Lua's `math.random()` with two arguments returns an integer within the specified range.

When called with no arguments, it returns a pseudo-random real number in between 0.0 and 1.0.

To get real numbers in a specified range, you need to do your own scaling; for example:

```
math.random() * 0.8 + 0.1
```

will give you a random real number between 0.1 and 0.9.  More generally:

```
math.random() * (hi - lo) + lo
```

which you can wrap in your own function if you like.

But I'll note that that's a fairly peculiar range. If you really want a random number selected from 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, ..., 0.9, then you should generate an integer in the range 1 to 9 and then divide it by 10.0:

```
math.random(1, 9) / 10.0
```

Keep in mind that most real numbers cannot be represented exactly in floating-point.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `math.random()` (no args) to generate a number between 0 and 1, and use that to blend between your two target numbers.

```
-- generates a random real number between a (inclusive) and b (exclusive)
function rand_real(a, b)
    return a + (b - a) * math.random()
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(math.random(10,90)) / 100
```

This generates a number from 10 to 90 and the division gives you a number from 0.1 to 0.9.

Comment: Yes, but it only gives you 79 (90-10+1) distinct values within that range; it's not likely that's what the OP wants. To get real random numbers, call `math.random()` with no arguments; see the other two answers.